# Android 2D game programming: using OpenGL or not?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've just started to develop games on Android. My first game is a 2D game and I'm wondering whether I should use OpenGL or not.

Does anyone have some advice on this?

Thanks a lot,
Viet

Comment: Thank you all for your quick and helpful replies. I'll go with OpenGL then :)

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL ES all the way! There are some good videos from last years IO on android game dev and the frame rates you can achieve going opengl vs canvas.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic

Also there are a handful of great 2d frameworks to simplify the process, the best in my opinion being [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know OpenGL ES will give better performance (especially on Tegra 2 devices). OpenGL ES is also harder to learn, but there are good tutorials and support libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you not to use OpenGL directly as it may seem difficult. Instead you can use a library like LIBGDX which provides easier functionality.

Check this tutorial:
http://m3ph1st0s.blogspot.ro/2012/12/create-games-with-libgdx-library-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use OpenGL ES if you want anything close to a respectable frame rate. OpenGL ES is hardware accelerated (uses the GPU), while other libraries mostly use the CPU.